# How to bypass scanning of request body if it exceed max limit for Azure Application Gateway WAF policy

Tags: azure, azure-waf

Is there any way we can scan request for < max request body size?, otherwise we want to bypass scan for request with contain attachment more than defined max size.
I tried custom rule but it didn't work

[image]

We need to define custom rules or perform other configuration in Azure WAF to increase response time.

Please let me know do we have any configuration or custom rules to achieve this functionality.

Comment: ...doing that kinda defeats the whole point of WAF.

Comment: yes but WAF took more time to scan whole attachment more than 200MB size, because of this we want some, configuration to bypass it. We have already implemented backend business logic to find security risk in attachment

Comment: BTW, not all requests will have a `Content-Length` header: it's common for large request bodies to be _streamed_ and neither the client nor server has an idea how long the request will actually be.

Comment: we send request with attachment in streamed format and another application through which we send request it always contain content-length.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to bypass the request body inspection is to disable it from the global settings.

[image: global parameters]